# Slow background-image scrolling with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, background-image

I'd like to apply slow scrolling to a background-image - something like parallax but simple. So I have the background (screen.css):

```
body { background: url('bcg.jpg') center top no-repeat fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; }
```

... and jQuery (jquery.init.js):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var bgheight = '100%';
    if($('body').height() >= $(window).height()){
        var bgheight = $('body').height() - $(window).height();
    }
    $('body').css('background-size',bgheight+'px auto');
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var bgpos = -(Math.max($('#pagewrap').scrollTop(),$('body').scrollTop())/10)+"px";
        $('body').css('background-position','50% '+bgpos);
    });
});
```

... and HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="cs">
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/screen.css" />
        <script src="/respond.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
            <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/jquery.init.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="pagewrap">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm surprised that it's working only in Chrome and IE 5. Do you have some tip for other browsers?

Comment: Right here: `$('body').css('background-position','50% '+bgpos);` you are adding pixels to a %, which you can't do. You need to get half of the screen in pixels, then add your `bgpos` to that.

Comment: OK, I can use 'center' instead of '50%', but it's still the problem with background scrolling in other browsers.